# Updates to the state of React context don't re-render children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm updating the shared state in context through a callback in the child component, but that does not cause a re-render, which results in the context in the child component having an initial value until the next re-render.

Is there a way to force the update of the child and a re-render once state is updated in the context provider?

My context provider:

```
const UserLocationContext = React.createContext()

export const useUserLocation = () => {
    return useContext(UserLocationContext)
}

export const UserLocationProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [ipUserLocation, setIpUserLocation] = useState(null)

    const updateIpUserLocation = (ipUserLocation) => {
        setIpUserLocation(ipUserLocation)
        console.log(ipUserLocation) //value is updated here immediately after the updateIpUserLocation call
    }
    return (
        <UserLocationContext.Provider value = {{ipUserLocation, updateIpUserLocation}}>
            {children}
        </UserLocationContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default UserLocationProvider
```

Child:

```
const LocationHandler = () => {
    const {ipUserLocation, updateIpUserLocation} = useUserLocation()
    
    useEffect(() => {
    const ip_url = `https://api.freegeoip.app/json/`
    const fetchIPLocation = async () => { 
        
        const result = await fetch(ip_url);
        const json = await result.json();
        updateIpUserLocation([json.latitude, json.longitude])
        console.log(ipUserLocation) //value here remains null until next re-render
    }
    fetchIPLocation()

    }, []);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `useState` is asynchronous, so `ipUserLocation` value is not updated immediately after `setIpUserLocation` gets called.

For the fix, you can add `ipUserLocation` as a dependency to `useEffect` that would help you to listen to all changes from `ipUserLocation` on `LocationHandler`.

```
const LocationHandler = () => {
    const {ipUserLocation, updateIpUserLocation} = useUserLocation()
    
    useEffect(() => {
    const ip_url = `https://api.freegeoip.app/json/`
    const fetchIPLocation = async () => { 
        
        const result = await fetch(ip_url);
        const json = await result.json();
        updateIpUserLocation([json.latitude, json.longitude])
    }
    fetchIPLocation()

    }, []);}

    //add another `useEffect` with `ipUserLocation` in dependencies
    useEffect(() => {
       //TODO: You can do something with updated `ipUserLocation` here
       console.log(ipUserLocation)
    }, [ipUserLocation])

    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the child component gets re-rendered when you update the state of the context. And this happens because you are using the **useContext** hook to listen to any change made to the context. What you can do to actually prove to yourself that the child gets re-rendered is adding this in the child component:

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(ipUserLocation);
}, [ipUserLocation])
```

With this useEffect the **console.log** will run everytime the child gets re-rendered and the **ipUserLocation** has changed.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html